# How to convert url encoded string to plain text in JAVA

Tags: java, url

I am looking for html references in a HTML page I am retrieving from the server. The problem is for all the hyperlinks I am retrieving, the text that I am getting is URL encoded. Lets say, the URL is  `"http://abc.def.com/gh?ij=x&kl=y&mn=z"`, my program parses it as `"http://abc.def.com/gh?ij=3Dx&amp;kl=3Dy&amp;mn=3Dz"` . (look at the difference around "=" and "&" in the two URL's) . Some searching on the Web tells me that the second URL is a URL encoded form of the first URL.

What should I do to retrieve the actual URL as it is, and not its URL encoded version? Right now, I am replacing =3D with 3D and `&amp;` with `&`, but that is a very bad hack.

Comment: That's not "URL encoded", it's a bit of an odd mixture of HTML/XML encoding of the ampersands and quoted-printable encoding of the equals signs.  Are you actually _parsing_ the HTML (with a proper HTML parser) or are you just treating it as text?

Comment: Why do you get it URL-encoded in the first place? That seems completely wrong. Why not fix that? What is the original text parsed, and how is it parsed?

Comment: No, I am just treating it as a text, since I am expecting to retrieve around only half a dozen urls out of the entire page which could up to tens of thousands of lines.

Comment: @JBNizet: I dont know, OK ? I tried a lot of different things, but it is just beyond my control. Try giving a solution I can use !

Comment: If a text file contains `http://abc.def.com/gh?ij=x&kl=y&mn=z`, and you get that out from your parser as `http://abc.def.com/gh?ij=3Dx&amp;kl=3Dy&amp;mn=3Dz`, then your parser has a serious bug. You should fix the parser, not try to fix the output. If you need help with that, **show how you parse the file**. We can't guess what your code looks like.

Comment: How about this: I dont have a parser. I am just reading from the inputstream, and displaying on the console.

Comment: Then how are you reading? Code that reads from an input stream and extracts some parts of it **IS** a parser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61202/discussion-between-raymond-232-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use java.net.URLDecoder